# Cannot delete /usr/bin/python3 on Catalina

Tags: catalina, python

I just upgraded my macbook from `Mojave` to `Catalina`, and after that, I upgraded `brew` as well.
The result is, now I have two `python3` binaries:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.7.6
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ whereis python3
/usr/bin/python3
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ /usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```

Wanted to delete the `3.7.3` version, but it didn't allow me:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python3
Password:
rm: /usr/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
```

So, there is no way to delete it?

By the way, only `python2.7` libs could be found in `/usr/lib`, but not those of `python3.7.3`.

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:/usr/lib$ ll *python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18 Feb 12 09:49 libpython.dylib -> libpython2.7.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  68 Feb 12 09:49 libpython2.7.dylib -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Feb 12 09:49 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:/usr/lib$ ll /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Feb 12 09:53 2.3 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Feb 12 09:53 2.5 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Feb 12 09:53 2.6 -> 2.7
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  320 Feb 25 12:03 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Feb 12 09:53 Current -> 2.7
```

There is `/usr/local/lib/python3.7`, but it seems that was installed together with `3.7.6` version, since `/usr/local/bin` is the location of the newer `3.7.6` binary?

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~$ ll -d /usr/local/lib/*python*
drwxr-xr-x  3 qxu  admin  96 Mar 10 11:30 /usr/local/lib/python3.7
```

Comment: You shouldn't delete macOS's preinstalled Pythons. Just ignore them. I recommend pyenv for managing Python installations.

Comment: @theonlygusti Hard to understand why `Catalina` or any version of macos does so, since we can delete whatever previous versions of `python3` on linux.

Comment: It is never recommended to delete the system-delivered Python (regardless of which Python version and OS we're talking about). There may be many implicit dependencies on the system Python that will break if the system Python were removed.